# F# - "self-filling" type property

Tags: c#, f#

In C#, I can have this:

```cs
public class A {
    ...
    private List<int> _items;
    public List<int> Items{
        get {
            if (_items == null){
                _items = DAL.FetchFromDB();
            }
            return _items;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I can intantiate class A, and when I ask for Items

1. I'm guaranteed to get it without explicitly having to fill the list.
2. I avoid repeated calls to the database

What would be an equivalent construct for F#?
I'm not sure how to make a type that does this...

I'm not necessarily asking for a mutable list; I'd like to know what a standard form of doing something like this is in F#, as I'm just learning the language.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "lazy-loading".

Comment: Specifically, see the `lazy` keyword as well as the documentation for `System.Lazy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a *one-to-one* translation to F#:

```ml
type A() =
    let mutable _items = null
    member this.items 
        with get() = 
            if _items = null then _items <- DAL.FetchFromDB()
            _items

let a = A()

let x = a.items  // db access here
let y = a.items
```

There are better (and shorter) ways to write equivalent code in F# using objects (see the other answer), but you don't need to create an object at all, you can simply define a function and as others already pointed out you can use the `lazy` keyword:

```ml
let items = 
    let v = lazy DAL.FetchFromDB()
    fun () -> v.Value

let x = items()  // db access here
let y = items()
```

or use the standard lazy value directly, I would prefer this because you are making explicit in the type of `items` that your value is lazy evaluated instead of hiding it behind a *magic* object property or function:

```ml
let items = lazy DAL.FetchFromDB()

let x = items.Value  // db access here
let y = items.Value
```

So now the type of `items` is `Lazy<'List<'T>>` which is always telling you that the value will be lazy computed, apart from that in this case the code is actually shorter.

Answer (score 7):

As ildjarn points out in the above comment, you can use the `lazy` keyword in an equivalent manner:

```ml
type A () =
    let items = lazy (DAL.FetchFromDB ())
    member this.Items with get () = items.Value
```

However, the question is whether it's 'idiomatic' F#, or 'good practice' in general?

The `Items` property isn't [referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29) (because it isn't deterministic), and Functional Programming tends to have a strong emphasis on referential transparency.

Granted: F# isn't a *pure* Functional language; it's a **Functional First** language. Still, it means that to get the most out of it, you should adopt a similar Functional First approach to your design.

The more Functional your own code is, the more value you get out of F#.

The more imperative, implicit, or object-oriented you make your F# code, the less you gain from it.

Thus, it's not always meaningful to attempt to translate C# verbatim to F# code. You can, but will you gain anything from it?

The bottom line is that it's possible to translate your C# to something similar to that in F#, but you should consider whether it's a good idea at all. There's nothing inherently wrong with using the `lazy` keyword, but the **implicitness** is something I'd rethink.

Comment: I agree with you but there is a way to make it explicit. Just return a lazy value and that way you make it explicit in the type.

Comment: @Gustavo It's not the laziness that's the problem. It's the implicit Query that's the problem: that it somehow is able to translate `()` to a list of integers. Unless it always returns the empty list, it *must* imply that it queries an external data source, and thus, it breaks *Isolation*.

Comment: I see your point. Anyway if you are aware that the value is Lazy at least you know it might be doing some calculation or query.

Comment: True; that's strongly implied :)

Comment: I had started with code that was similar to Gustavo's first posted code, but then rearranged a number of functions and avoided using the lazy keyword.